# PHP likely chance

Tags: php

Okay, so i don't really know how I go about this.

I'm currently working on a lottery system for a game.

I have a table with virtual items which I want to randomly select by a likely chance.

Table examples:

```
ID = 1, item_name = Sword, likely_chance = 75  
ID = 2, Item_name = 10,000, likely_chance = 20
```

For id 2, 10,000 represents 10,000 coins.

I want to come up with an algorithm which will select a item with a higher chance of selecting a higher likely chance but also still be able to win a item with a lower likely chance rarely.

Answer (score 1):

If you have items with "likely chances" of `C1`, `C2`, `C3`...`Cn`, then you can calculate the sum `Ctotal`.

Then, you can get a random value between `0` and `Ctotal`, and walk through your array (order is irrelevant) until the sum of "skipped" items exceeds this random value.

For example, in your case, `Ctotal = 75 + 20 = 95`. Get a random number between 0 and 95, and if it is less than 75 - give a sword; else - give 10000 coins. It will provide a fair winnings distribution according to your likely chances - 78.95% and 21.05%, respectively.

```
$items = ['Sword', '10000 coins'];
$chances = [70, 25];

$ctotal = array_sum($chances); echo "Total is $ctotal\n";
$rand = rand(0, $ctotal); echo "Rand is $rand\n";

$i = 0;
$currentSum = 0;
while (true)
{
    $currentSum += $chances[$i];
    if ($currentSum >= $rand)
    {
        echo "You win: ".$items[$i];
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Here is the [working Demo](http://ideone.com/qOQ8Ui). Note that IDEOne remembers the last output and doesn't run this program again every time. The output will appear to be the same, but it is not.

Comment: I don't want a random number though, I want the algorithm to have higher chances of picking an item with a higher likely chance first. This way a user has higher chances of getting a item that isn't rare. Say for exampe, the chances of getting a sword is a 75% chance.

Comment: @Viacom If I understand your description correctly, then it is actually not 75% change, but 78.95% (75 / 95). Probably, you didn't understand my algorithm. Just check the demo. You will have to use random numbers anyway, if you want to provide a randomized algorithm.

Comment: How can I go about doing this if it's all stored inside a table instead of an array?

Comment: @Viacom It is just an example. If you have a table, read data to an array and work with it. Just google for "how to use sql in php".